# How to use camera on packed Tkinter canvas (opencv)

Tags: python, opencv, canvas, camera, tkinter

could someone explain me why after modyfication of commented out code there is no camera view more?
I get error message

> "    self.a = Image.fromarray(self.capture)#PIL 1.6#
>   AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'fromarray'"

from x.update_video method.
Commented code is from topic [OpenCV (cv2 in Python) VideoCapture not releasing camera after deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460706/opencv-cv2-in-python-videocapture-not-releasing-camera-after-deletion)
I am very new to Tkinter and found no help in tutorials.
I suppose it is due to frame is packed as well as canvas. But there must be any solution...

```
class App:
      def __init__(self, master,cam):
##    root = tk.Tk()
##    videoframe = tk.LabelFrame(root,text='Captured video')
##    videoframe.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=1,rowspan=1,padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)
##    canvas = tk.Canvas(videoframe, width=640,height=480)
##    canvas.grid(column=0,row=0)
##    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(2)
##    x = vid(cam,root,canvas)
##    root.after(0,x.update_video)
##    button = tk.Button(text='Quit',master=videoframe,command=root.destroy)
##    button.grid(column=0,row=1)
##    root.mainloop()
##    del cam
        frame = LabelFrame(master,text='Captured video')
        frame.pack()
        canvas = Canvas(frame, width=640,height=480)
        canvas.pack(side=TOP)

        x = vid(cam,master,canvas)
        master.after(0,x.update_video)

        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=master.destroy)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.hi_there = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=LEFT)
      def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"
root = Tk()
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
app = App(root,cam)
root.mainloop()
del cam
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you precisely what the problem is: you're trying to call `fromarray` on a class that has no such method. That probably means that `Image` is not what you think it is, so start by verifying for yourself exactly what `Image` is, and whether it's supposed to have an `fromarray` method.

Answer (score 0):

My image is a capture from camera.

```
 def update_video(self):
        (self.readsuccessful,self.f) = self.cam.read()
        self.capture = cv2.cvtColor(self.f, cv2.COLOR_RGB2RGBA) #cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        self.a = Image.fromarray(self.capture)#nowe w PIL 1.6 #PIL.Image.VERSION=1.1.7
        self.b = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=self.a) ...
```

It works in commented version.` Though Image class has the method fromarray although is not yet well docummented.

Answer (score 0):

Brayan's answer was a bit confusing me, but we is right. My problem was caused by include.
Never use import *. It overwrote Image class from PIL module with Image class from Tkinter and this class has no such method. Thanks.

Comment: So you finally figured it out, yes?